# Why isn't HashAlgorithm.Dispose public?

Tags: .net, idisposable, hashalgorithm

Why isn't `HashAlgorithm.Dispose` public?

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

I understand that it is an explicit interface implementation and can still be called. I am trying to work out the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx). The only way to call this method is to cast to a `IDisposable` object. One good example of when this might be useful is when you have a class which implements two interfaces that both have the same method name and you want to provide a different implementation for each of them.

Comment: I understand that. Trying to work out what the reasoning is behind it.
I have never seen an explicit implementation of IDisposable. Editted question to make clearer.

Comment: While I don't know the reason for explicitly implementing the `IDisposable` interface in the `HashAlgorithm` class I may say that this is a **BAD** practice. Although the using block will work with classes that do have an explicit `IDisposable` implementation, developers who are exploring the object model may not notice that the object has a `Dispose` method and therefore may not take advantage of early cleanup.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Explicit implementation of `IDisposable` is good in cases where the implementation won't do anything and the class wants to advertise that it's not necessary to call it on things which are known to be of its particular type.  I'd posit that the proper way to implement such a do-nothing method would be to explicitly implement an empty method; explicit implementation is not proper if the `Dispose` method is chained as shown above, but some coding policies may require that all dispose implementations chain as shown.